# Canny draws contour around frame

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opencv, emgucv, canny-operator

I am having an issue with the Canny function.
It produces lines around my frame. So when I use my FindContour function afterwards it draws a contour around my frame. I want to look at my biggest contour which should be my object but is my frame in this situation. When the Canny function clearly shows one shape, then the function is most likely to draw a big contour around my frame.

If have seen there are ways to avoid this problem by converting the image. When I do this I get an error though. Here is my code.

```
private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_capture != null && _capture.Ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            _capture.Retrieve(imgOriginal, 0);
            CvInvoke.CvtColor(imgOriginal, imgHSV, ColorConversion.Bgr2Hsv); //Convert the captured frame from BGR to HSV
            CvInvoke.InRange(imgHSV, new ScalarArray(new MCvScalar(iLowH, iLowS, iLowV)), new ScalarArray(new MCvScalar(iHighH, iHighS, iHighV)), imgThres);
            CvInvoke.Erode(imgThres, imgThres, CvInvoke.GetStructuringElement(ElementShape.Ellipse, new Size(5, 5), new Point(-1, -1)), new Point(-1, -1), 3, BorderType.Constant, new MCvScalar(255, 255, 255));
            CvInvoke.Dilate(imgThres, imgThres, CvInvoke.GetStructuringElement(ElementShape.Ellipse, new Size(5, 5), new Point(-1, -1)), new Point(-1, -1), 3, BorderType.Constant, new MCvScalar(255, 255, 255));
            CvInvoke.Canny(imgThres, imgCanny, 100, 200, 3);
            CvInvoke.Invert(imgCanny, imgCanny, DecompMethod.Svd);
            FindLargestContour(imgCanny, imgContour);
            pictureBox1.Image = imgOriginal.Bitmap;
            pictureBox2.Image = imgCanny.Bitmap;
        }
    }

    private void FindLargestContour(IInputOutputArray imgCanny, IInputOutputArray imgContour)
    {
        int largest_contour_index = 0;
        double largest_area = 0;
        VectorOfPoint largestContour;
        using (Mat hierachy = new Mat())
        using (VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint())
        {
            IOutputArray hierarchy;
            CvInvoke.FindContours(imgCanny, contours, hierachy, RetrType.Tree, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
            for (int i = 0; i < contours.Size; i++)
            {
                MCvScalar color = new MCvScalar(0, 0, 255);
                double a = CvInvoke.ContourArea(contours[i], false);  //  Find the area of contour
                if (a > largest_area)
                {
                    largest_area = a;
                    largest_contour_index = i;                //Store the index of largest contour
                }
                CvInvoke.DrawContours(imgContour, contours, largest_contour_index, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0));
            }
            CvInvoke.DrawContours(imgContour, contours, largest_contour_index, new MCvScalar(0, 0, 255), 5, LineType.EightConnected, hierachy);
            largestContour = new VectorOfPoint(contours[largest_contour_index].ToArray());
        }
    }
```

The error is as following when I uncomment the Invert function.

```
CvException: OpenCV: type == CV_32F || type == CV_64F
```

I used to have my code in c++ and there it didn't give this issue of drawing a contour around the frame. Maybe I should use different threshold values for my Canny function? Could another solution be to find the area of my frame and then take that area out of the comparison?

Thank you!

Comment: I have not used C# before. So I might have understood this wrong. However, have you made sure that the object of interest is white and the background is black. OpenCV considers the white pixels as the object of interest. I am seeing that you invert the binary image after canny detection. Try not doing that if your object of interest is made black in that step.

Comment: The object of interest is indeed white and the background is black. The inverter was to test whether making the object of interest black was fixing the issue. Which made no sense but I had to try it anyways. But I couldn't even get the inverter working so haven't tried it in the end. But yeah, my object is white and the background is black. This exact code in c++ worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most fancy workaround but I edited the if loop that looks at the largest area of a contour.

So from

```
if (a > largest_area)
{
    largest_area = a;
    largest_contour_index = i;
}
```

I went to

```
if (a > largest_area && a < 0.92 * (_capture.Width * _capture.Height))
{
    largest_area = a;
    largest_contour_index = i;
}
```

This way the code should not save the contour which has a size almost as big as the entire frame.